# How do I authenticate a user for my facebook app and then post to their wall for them?

Tags: php, facebook

I created a facebook app under my companies facebook account. We have a website that has a lot of customers and I want to them to be able to authorize our app to post on their own walls for them.

How can I do this in PHP?? I have looked all over but can't find a good coded example.

Comment: Have you downloaded and looked at the documentation for the Facebook PHP SDK? Because that's one of the basic examples: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/

Answer (score 0):

Search google for an example with the **publish_stream** permission.

Comment: Ok thanks. I have made some progress. I have authenticated a user and with their user id posted to their wall as them. However, I am having a problem with a "page" account. First it doesn't ask them to authenticate the app, but it it listed under their apps when I log in as them. Second, I can post to the page's wall. Any ideas?